# Refresh data in ViewPager when returning

Tags: android, android-fragments

Activity A:
[image]
In this activity there is 1 ViewPager containing 2 Fragments which contain a List of Products. 1 for recent products and 1 for popular products. When i click on a product (regardless which fragment is active) i will go to the detailview of that product (See picture of Activity B).

Activity B:
[image]
In this activity there are the possiblities to like, reply to and share a prodoct by clicking the corresponding floathingActionButton. When one of these actions is performed, the data in this activity is updated.

The data will be kept in an singleton which is accessable in both activities. When an action in performed in Activity B, the data will be updated. However when i go back to Activity A, the lists in both activities are not refreshed. 
I have tried overwrite the pager in the onRestart in Activity A, but the data did not refresh.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: When you post a question with images without code, and you want people to magically understand what the problem is !

Answer (score -1):

I think you should reload the data again and call

`yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

to refresh the adapter.